# postfix+dovecot doesn't receive email

Tags: email, dovecot

Could you please help me with dovecot's issue, couldn't receive email. Bunch of postfix+dovecot+squirrelmail

Here is my postconf -n

```
[root@mail Maildir]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = domain.net
myhostname = mail.domain.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. See you are going correct. Also make sure you create public / private keys and save in the right location and set correct permission with chmod

Also before doing anything check /etc/postfix/master.cf

See if you have uncommented lines with smtp, submission and smtps

Let me know in case of a problem

http://www.binarytides.com/install-postfix-dovecot-debian/